# Making Postgres Query Faster. More Indexes? 

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I'm running Geodjango/Postgres 9.1/PostGIS and I'm trying to get the following query (and others like it) to run faster.

[query snipped for brevity]

```
SELECT "crowdbreaks_incomingkeyword"."keyword_id"
       , COUNT("crowdbreaks_incomingkeyword"."keyword_id") AS "cnt" 
  FROM "crowdbreaks_incomingkeyword"
 INNER JOIN "crowdbreaks_tweet"
       ON ("crowdbreaks_incomingkeyword"."tweet_id"
          = "crowdbreaks_tweet"."tweet_id")
  LEFT OUTER JOIN "crowdbreaks_place"
    ON ("crowdbreaks_tweet"."place_id"
       = "crowdbreaks_place"."place_id") 
 WHERE (("crowdbreaks_tweet"."coordinates"
        @ ST_GeomFromEWKB(E'\\001 ... \\000\\000\\000\\0008@'::bytea)
       OR ST_Overlaps("crowdbreaks_place"."bounding_box"
                     , ST_GeomFromEWKB(E'\\001...00\\000\\0008@'::bytea)
       )) 
   AND "crowdbreaks_tweet"."created_at" > E'2012-04-17 15:46:12.109893'
   AND "crowdbreaks_tweet"."created_at" < E'2012-04-18 15:46:12.109899' ) 
 GROUP BY "crowdbreaks_incomingkeyword"."keyword_id"
         , "crowdbreaks_incomingkeyword"."keyword_id"
    ;
```

Here is what the crowdbreaks_tweet table looks like:

```
\d+ crowdbreaks_tweet;
                       Table "public.crowdbreaks_tweet"
    Column     |           Type           | Modifiers | Storage  | Description 
---------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+-------------
 tweet_id      | bigint                   | not null  | plain    | 
 tweeter       | bigint                   | not null  | plain    | 
 text          | text                     | not null  | extended | 
 created_at    | timestamp with time zone | not null  | plain    | 
 country_code  | character varying(3)     |           | extended | 
 place_id      | character varying(32)    |           | extended | 
 coordinates   | geometry                 |           | main     | 
Indexes:
    "crowdbreaks_tweet_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (tweet_id)
    "crowdbreaks_tweet_coordinates_id" gist (coordinates)
    "crowdbreaks_tweet_created_at" btree (created_at)
    "crowdbreaks_tweet_place_id" btree (place_id)
    "crowdbreaks_tweet_place_id_like" btree (place_id varchar_pattern_ops)
Check constraints:
    "enforce_dims_coordinates" CHECK (st_ndims(coordinates) = 2)
    "enforce_geotype_coordinates" CHECK (geometrytype(coordinates) = 'POINT'::text OR coordinates IS NULL)
    "enforce_srid_coordinates" CHECK (st_srid(coordinates) = 4326)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "crowdbreaks_tweet_place_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (place_id) REFERENCES crowdbreaks_place(place_id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
Referenced by:
    TABLE "crowdbreaks_incomingkeyword" CONSTRAINT "crowdbreaks_incomingkeyword_tweet_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (tweet_id) REFERENCES crowdbreaks_tweet(tweet_id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
    TABLE "crowdbreaks_tweetanswer" CONSTRAINT "crowdbreaks_tweetanswer_tweet_id_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (tweet_id_id) REFERENCES crowdbreaks_tweet(tweet_id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
Has OIDs: no
```

And here is the explain analyze for the query:

```
 HashAggregate  (cost=184022.03..184023.18 rows=115 width=4) (actual time=6381.707..6381.769 rows=62 loops=1)
   ->  Hash Join  (cost=103857.48..183600.24 rows=84357 width=4) (actual time=1745.449..6377.505 rows=3453 loops=1)
         Hash Cond: (crowdbreaks_incomingkeyword.tweet_id = crowdbreaks_tweet.tweet_id)
         ->  Seq Scan on crowdbreaks_incomingkeyword  (cost=0.00..36873.97 rows=2252597 width=12) (actual time=0.008..2136.839 rows=2252597 loops=1)
         ->  Hash  (cost=102535.68..102535.68 rows=80544 width=8) (actual time=1744.815..1744.815 rows=3091 loops=1)
               Buckets: 4096  Batches: 4  Memory Usage: 32kB
               ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=16574.93..102535.68 rows=80544 width=8) (actual time=112.551..1740.651 rows=3091 loops=1)
                     Hash Cond: ((crowdbreaks_tweet.place_id)::text = (crowdbreaks_place.place_id)::text)
                     Filter: ((crowdbreaks_tweet.coordinates @ '0103000020E61000000100000005000000AE47E17A141E5FC00000000000003840AE47E17A141E5FC029ED0DBE30B14840A4703D0AD7A350C029ED0DBE30B14840A4703D0AD7A350C00000000000003840AE47E17A141E5FC00000000000003840'::geometry) OR ((crowdbreaks_place.bounding_box && '0103000020E61000000100000005000000AE47E17A141E5FC00000000000003840AE47E17A141E5FC029ED0DBE30B14840A4703D0AD7A350C029ED0DBE30B14840A4703D0AD7A350C00000000000003840AE47E17A141E5FC00000000000003840'::geometry) AND _st_overlaps(crowdbreaks_place.bounding_box, '0103000020E61000000100000005000000AE47E17A141E5FC00000000000003840AE47E17A141E5FC029ED0DBE30B14840A4703D0AD7A350C029ED0DBE30B14840A4703D0AD7A350C00000000000003840AE47E17A141E5FC00000000000003840'::geometry)))
                     ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on crowdbreaks_tweet  (cost=15874.18..67060.28 rows=747873 width=125) (actual time=96.012..940.462 rows=736784 loops=1)
                           Recheck Cond: ((created_at > '2012-04-17 15:46:12.109893+00'::timestamp with time zone) AND (created_at < '2012-04-18 15:46:12.109899+00'::timestamp with time zone))
                           ->  Bitmap Index Scan on crowdbreaks_tweet_crreated_at  (cost=0.00..15687.22 rows=747873 width=0) (actual time=94.259..94.259 rows=736784 loops=1)
                                 Index Cond: ((created_at > '2012-04-17 15:46:12.109893+00'::timestamp with time zone) AND (created_at < '2012-04-18 15:46:12.109899+00'::timestamp with time zone))
                     ->  Hash  (cost=217.11..217.11 rows=6611 width=469) (actual time=15.926..15.926 rows=6611 loops=1)
                           Buckets: 1024  Batches: 4  Memory Usage: 259kB
                           ->  Seq Scan on crowdbreaks_place  (cost=0.00..217.11 rows=6611 width=469) (actual time=0.005..6.908 rows=6611 loops=1)
 Total runtime: 6381.903 ms
(17 rows)
```

That's a pretty bad runtime for the query. Ideally, I'd like to get results back in a second or two.

I've increased shared_buffers on Postgres to 2GB (I have 8GB of RAM) but other than that I'm not quite sure what to do. What are my options? Should I do fewer joins? Are there any other indexes I can throw on there? The sequential scan on crowdbreaks_incomingkeyword doesn't make sense to me. It's a table of foreign keys to other tables, and thus has indexes on it.

Comment: If I 'set enable seqscan to off;' before running the explain analyze, the query time reduces to 1.8 seconds. However, everything I read says I shouldn't really do this.

Comment: I pasted your EXPLAIN output here: http://explain.depesz.com/s/EfH to get a better view.

Comment: BTW: what is the impact of duplicating the term `crowdbreaks_incomingkeyword"."keyword_id` in the GROUP BY clause? (could be that the optimiser forgets to remove this redundancy, and computes the specificity of groups as 1/squared(number of groups)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Judging from your comment I would try two things:

- Raise [**statistics target**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-query.html#GUC-DEFAULT-STATISTICS-TARGET) for involved columns (and run `ANALYZE`).

  ```
  ALTER TABLE tbl ALTER COLUMN column SET STATISTICS 1000;
  ```

The data distribution may be uneven. A bigger sample may provide the query planner with more accurate estimates.

- Play with the [**cost settings**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/runtime-config-query.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-QUERY-CONSTANTS) in `postgresql.conf`. Your sequential scans might need to be more expensive compared to your index scans to give good estimates.

Try to lower the cost for `cpu_index_tuple_cost` and set `effective_cache_size` to something as high as three quaters of your total RAM for a dedicated DB server.

Comment: Do I raise statistics for the columns I use to filter, the columns I select, or both?

Comment: @Khandelwal: The ones you filter and join on are relevant for planning. Just selecting is irrelevant.

Comment: Raising statistics doesn't seem to make any difference. I set statistics to 1000 on crowdbreaks_tweet.created_at, and crowdbreaks_incomingkeyword.tweet_id and ran analyze on both tables. That didn't change the plan.

Comment: Also, I lowered random_page_cost from 4 to 2 and restarted the postgres server. According to the documentation that should have made postgres choose index scans instead of seq scans.

Comment: @Khandelwal: If most of the relevant parts of your database fit into RAM, you should set `random_page_cost` even lower - only slightly above `seq_page_cost`. I have `1` for `seq_page_cost` and `1.1` for `random_page_cost` for db clusters that are mostly cached. In RAM random access is basically just as fast as sequential access. Only on disc it is *much* slower.

Comment: Another setting I have often found helpful is raising `cpu_tuple_cost` to somewhere in the range of 0.03 to 0.05.  This may be somewhat redundant to lowering `cpu_index_tuple_cost`, since cost factors are relative.  BTW, the reason raising `effective_cache_size` would help is that it tells the planner how much of an index is likely to stay in cache when repeatedly accessed within a single query; higher values tend to make indexed access look less expensive.

Comment: Normally, I set the effective_cache_size as high as possible (available memory - memory used by all processes. In your case about 8-2=6GB) I tend to keep shared_buffers low. I've heard rumours about shared_buffers being a pain om VMs (probably because they impose some kind of core-lock). Trusting on the OS's LRU disk buffers seems to be a good choice. @Khandelwal: could you please add the resulting query plan to your question?